# Kreyszig Functional Analysis - Section 2.8 Problem 9

Tags: functional-analysis

hope you can help me with my attempt at a proof of Kreyszig's Functional Analysis Section 2.8 Problem 9. Cheers!

Let $f:X \rightarrow K$ be a linear functional, where $K$ is the field of scalars in the underlying vectorspace structure. Suppose that $f\neq0$ and let $x_0 \in X \setminus \mathcal{N}(f)$ be fixed. Show that all $x \in X$ has a unique representation $x = \alpha x_0 + y$, for some $y \in \mathcal{N}(f)$ and some $\alpha \in K$.

(Proof edit based on comments:)

**Existence:** Let $f(x) = f(x)\frac{f(x_0)}{f(x_0)}$, by using linearity we can re-arrange to get $f(x - \frac{f(x)}{f(x_0)}x_0) = 0$ this means that $x - \frac{f(x)}{f(x_0)}x_0=y$ for some $y \in \mathcal{N}(f)$, and $\alpha := f(x) / f(x_0) \in K$.

**Uniqueness**: Suppose that $x = \alpha_1 x_0 + y_1 = \alpha_2 x_0 + y_2$ are two representations, then $f(x) = \alpha_1 f(x_0) = \alpha_2 f(x_0)$. Hence $\alpha_1 = \alpha_2$, giving $\alpha_1 x_0 + y_1 = \alpha_1 x_0 + y_2$ which implies $y_1 = y_2$.

Comment: Just take $y=x-\alpha x_0$ where $\alpha$ is defined as $\frac {f(x)} {f(x_0)}$

Comment: We have $$f(x)=\frac{f(x)}{f(f_0)}f(x_0) $$ thus $$x-\frac{f(x)}{f(x_0)}x_0 \in \mathcal{N}(f).$$

Comment: Nice! Thanks guys.